# Passing result from AJAX call to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on my first HTML form that performs an AJAX HTTP POST using jQuery. When a user makes a change to an input text field and tabs out of the field it triggers the AJAX script which in turn calls a PHP script which performs a database update.

The AJAX call can be successful but the database update could be unsuccessful (e.g. database related error) - I would like to insert the result of the PHP script into an alert. I can echo out any errors in in my PHP script, but I'm not sure how to get that into the appropriate alert.

Here's my Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#storeManager").change(function(){
        var storeManager = $("#storeManager").val();
        $.post('editProject.php', { storeManager: storeManager, id: '1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F' }, function(data) {
            $("#managerRow").addClass("success");

        }).fail(function () {
            // no data available in this context
            $("#managerRow").addClass("danger");
            $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
        });
     }); 
});
</script>
```

Here's the HTML table that contains the input field that triggers the AJAX call:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Store</td>
    <td>Acme Widgets Inc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Retailer</td>
    <td>Acme Corp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Store ID</td>
    <td>9876543</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>NSW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="managerRow">
    <td>Manager</td>
    <td>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="storeManager" name="storeManager" value="Peter Johns">

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>9222 3456</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="" id="ajaxAlert" role="alert"></div>
```

What I would like to do is, if there is any error from the editProject.php script that it stores in a $error variable and can echo out, to then insert this into the ajaxAlert and add a class: alert:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="ajaxAlert" role="alert">The error from the database update from the php script appears here</div>
```

I'm new to jQuery and AJAX and everything I've tried hasn't updated the alert with the new class and alert text and I can't seem to find a similar to example that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `append()` in jquery. Try using

```
fail(function () {
        // no data available in this context
        $("#managerRow").addClass("danger");
        //append error to the div using its ID
        $('#ajaxAlert').append('error from database');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: instead of .fail();

```
    var storeManager = $("#storeManager").val();
    $.post('editProject.php', { storeManager: storeManager, id: '1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F' }, function(data) {
        alert(data);

    },function (xhr, data, jx) {
        // the error function should be mentioned like this with comma after success fucntion
        console.log(xhr);//for console logging the error...
         alert(xhr);//NOW you will get data and alert will show...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
----php start---------     
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('','','','');
    $sql = "UPDATE accounts set name='".$_POST['name']." WHERE email='".$_POST['mail']."' LIMIT 1";
    if(mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) === true)){
        echo 'success'; exit();
    }else{
        echo 'connection error'; exit();
    }
}
----php end  ---------
<script>
    function test(){
        var formDATA = {
            'name': $('#input_name').val(),
            'mail': $('#input_mail').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: formDATA,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 'success'){
                    $('#result').html('Your Update Was Complete');
                }else{
                    $('#result').html();
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input id="input_mail" type="text" value="">
<input id="input_name" type="text" value="">
<button onclick="test();">Test Ajax</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Try something simple, this is a very basic version of ajax and php all in one page. Since the button triggers the function you don't even need a form (doesn't mean you shouldn't use one). But i left it simple so you could follow everything.

Sorry when i added php open and closing tags it didn't show up as code. Also don't forget to include your jquery resources.

WARNING: DO NOT DO QUERIES LIKE THE EXAMPLE, THIS IS A HUGE SECURITY RISK!